# British LaTeX files with Emacs and Hunspell

Tags: emacs, dictionaries

I am using Hunspell with Emacs. 
In my init.el I set the dictionary list as follow:

```
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(
        (nil       "[A-Za-z]" "[^A-Za-z]" "" nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8)
        ("english" "[A-Za-z]" "[^A-Za-z]" "" nil ("-d" "en_GB") nil utf-8)))
```

If I spell check this TeX file:

```
\documentclass {paper}

\begin{document}
The word i.e. and contracted words aren't accepted. 
\end{document}

% Local IspellDict: english
# LocalWords:
```

the words "i.e." and "aren't" are not recognized, as every word containing dots or single quotes. 
Setting `OTHERCHARS` in the dictionary list  to `"['.]"` does not help.

Anyway, if I change the dictionary "en_GB" to "en_US", it works.

So it seems that the problem is in my dictionary. I downloaded it from the link:
http://en-gb.pyxidium.co.uk/dictionary/en_GB.zip  found on the site:
http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries .

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a LaTeX problem at all.

Comment: @Seamus: I could delete it, but I wonder, there are 184 questions concerned with using LaTeX with Emacs/AUCTeX, how is this one different from the others?  And I should also note that there are 92 questions for TeXnicCenter, 47 for Texstudio, 54 for Winedt etc. Since TeX is system that doesn't come with an editor of its own, the community seems much interested to the editors through which one can produces the actual documents.

Comment: @antonio Good points! Perhaps we can discuss it on [meta]?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: I did: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/speaking-of-latex-editors

Comment: This issue has been around for years: you see the same in Firefox using the en-GB dictionary (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=318040). Thus there is not much to say about it at the TeX end, I'm afraid.

Comment: +1 @JosephWright: I found an "answer" eventually. One reason why it could be useful to _discuss_ the question here (and not on an Emacs only context) is that there could be LaTeX specific workarounds such as `\newcommand{\ie}{i.e.\ }` not meaningful for a non-LaTeX user. Besides the Mozilla workarounds (bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=318040 ) can be limited in scope, since Emacs can in part control the spelling of dots etc. setting the OTHERCHARS argument of the dictionary list to "['.]".

Comment: Use `aspell` instead of `hunspell` or `ispell`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit. Thanks, and can you please tell in what what way it is better? It seems there is a lot of hype on Hunspell. For ex. [emacswiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveSpell), says "Hunspell, having many updated dictionaries and an ispell-compatible mode, makes a good replacement to ispell/aspell if your language has more complex rules than aspell can handle".

Comment: `aspell` recognizes _i.e._ and _aren't_. English is not complex, so you don't need hunspell.